# python textwrap with \n is placing newline mid paragraph

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im reading text from a file, and trying to use textwrap to beautify it a bit. However when I come across paragraphs that have \n the textwrap seems to cut some sentences off mid-line onto a newline.

```
import textwrap
text = "Extremely we promotion remainder eagerness enjoyment an. Ham her demands removal brought minuter raising invited.\nContented consisted continual curiosity contained get ham.\nForth child dried in in aware do. You had met they song how feel lain evil near. Small she avoid six yet table china. And bed make say been then dine mrs.\nTo household rapturous fulfilled attempted on so. "
textOut = textwrap.fill(text, 100, replace_whitespace=False)
print(textOut)
```

What im currently getting: (you can see it newlines after "in")

```
Extremely we promotion remainder eagerness enjoyment an. Ham her demands removal brought minuter
raising invited.
Contented consisted continual curiosity contained get ham.
Forth child dried in
in aware do. You had met they song how feel lain evil near. Small she avoid six yet table china. And
bed make say been then dine mrs.
To household rapturous fulfilled attempted on so.
```

What I want to get:

```
Extremely we promotion remainder eagerness enjoyment an. Ham her demands removal brought minuter
raising invited.
Contented consisted continual curiosity contained get ham.
Forth child dried in in aware do. You had met they song how feel lain evil near. Small she avoid six
yet table china. And bed make say been then dine mrs.
To household rapturous fulfilled attempted on so.
```

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `textwrap.fill()` function doesn't take existing newlines into account; those are seen as just more characters. It is [explicitly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill) as operating on a single paragraph:

> Wraps the single paragraph in *text*

Split your input text on newlines producing paragraph, wrap paragraph, then re-join:

```
paragraphs = text.splitlines()
textOut = "\n".join([
    textwrap.fill(p, 100, replace_whitespace=False) for p in paragraphs
])
```

You probably used `replace_whitespace` because you were seeing your newlines removed. With the above treatment, you can drop that now:

```
paragraphs = text.splitlines()
textOut = "\n".join([textwrap.fill(p, 100) for p in paragraphs])
```